# Tikzpicture of 3 perfect hexagons overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, nodes, tikz-node

for some university stuff I need to align 3 perfect hexagons and they have to be overlapping, see attached image below.
That means, I need equal distance between every pair of nodes.
Of course I could calculate that by hand and give each node its coordinates.
But is there a simpler way?
E.g. using the angle? If I could use angles instead of "above right" in the following example, I would be very happy. But I haven't found a way yet.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto,
node distance=1cm, scale=1, 
transform shape, align=center, 
state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2.5em}]

\node[state]    (MP) {$v_{10}$};  
\node[state, above right=of MP] (GS) {$v_{10}$};
\node[state, above left=of MP] (BP) {$v_{10}$};

\path[-] (MP) edge node {} (GS)
(MP) edge node {} (GS)
(BP) edge node {} (MP);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any help and/or ideas appreciated!

Cheers

[image: The result I want]

Edit: This is what I've got with the help of Ignasi. And it's perfect.
As a bonus: How could I center my triangle D without "guessing" its size? Currently size 3.5 isn't perfect and its "slightly" offset. Not that it would be visible by eye, it's just out of curiosity! If using a node would be simpler, how could I know its coordinates exactly? :)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=6cm, outer sep=0pt},
triangle/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum size=3.5cm, outer sep=0pt, shape border rotate=180},
state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2.5em}]
\node[hexagon] (A) {A};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 4] at (A.corner 1) (B){B};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 2] at (B.corner 5) (C){C};
\node[triangle, anchor=corner 3] at (B.corner 4) (D) {D};

% Top Hexagon
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (4) at (B.corner 1) {$v_{4}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (3) at (B.corner 2) {$v_{3}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (2) at (B.corner 3) {$v_{2}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (1) at (B.corner 4) {$v_{1}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (6) at (B.corner 5) {$v_{6}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (5) at (B.corner 6) {$v_{5}$};

% Right Hexagon
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (7) at (C.corner 1) {$v_{7}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (11) at (C.corner 3) {$v_{11}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (10) at (C.corner 4) {$v_{10}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (9) at (C.corner 5) {$v_{9}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (8) at (C.corner 6) {$v_{8}$};

% Left Hexagon
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (15) at (A.corner 2) {$v_{15}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (14) at (A.corner 3) {$v_{14}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (13) at (A.corner 4) {$v_{13}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (A.corner 5) {$v_{12}$};

% Edges
\foreach \i in {1,...,14}{
    \path[-]
    (\i) edge node {} (\the\numexpr\i+1);
}
\path[-]
(1) edge node {} (6)
(6) edge node {} (11)
(11) edge node {} (1)
(15) edge node {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: The hexagons you drew do not really overlap. They just have pairwise a common vertex. Are they meant to have the same size?

Comment: By "overlapping" I mean having a common vertex pairwise. 
Yes, I want every hexagon to have the same size and consist out of 6 vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}
                
\begin{document}
                             
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=2cm, outer sep=0pt, draw},
  mylabel/.style={circle, inner sep=1pt}
  ]

\node[hexagon] (A) {A};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 4] at (A.corner 1) (B){B};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 2] at (B.corner 5) (C){C};

\foreach \i in {A,B,C}{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}
        \filldraw (\i.corner \j) circle(1pt);
    }
    
\node[mylabel, right= 0mm of B.corner 6] {$v_1$};
\node[mylabel, above right= 0mm of B.corner 1] {$v_2$};
\node[mylabel, above left= 0mm of B.corner 2] {$v_3$};       
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Final version?**

Some little modifications to OP's code:

- Position of `D` label is computed with `barycentric cs`. It seems we need specific coordinates (anchors names were not accepted) and no space between coordinates list.
- `state` definition has been changed to simulate distance between edges and vertices. `states` are white filled circles and in internal drawn circle has been added with a `path picture` option.

This is new code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}
                
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=6cm, outer sep=0pt, draw},
state/.style={circle, fill=white, minimum size=2.5em, path picture={\draw[black] (path picture bounding box.center) circle(1em);}}]
\node[hexagon] (A) {A};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 4] at (A.corner 1) (B){B};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 2] at (B.corner 5) (C){C};
%\node at (3,1.8) {D};
\coordinate (aux1) at (B.corner 4);
\coordinate (aux2) at (B.corner 5);
\coordinate (aux3) at (C.corner 3);
\node at (barycentric cs:aux1=1,aux2=1,aux3=1) {D};

% Top Hexagon
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (B.corner 1) {$v_{4}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (B.corner 2) {$v_{3}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (B.corner 3) {$v_{2}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (B.corner 4) {$v_{1}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (B.corner 5) {$v_{6}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (B.corner 6) {$v_{5}$};

% Right Hexagon
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (C.corner 1) {$v_{7}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (C.corner 3) {$v_{11}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (C.corner 4) {$v_{10}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (C.corner 5) {$v_{9}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (C.corner 6) {$v_{8}$};

% Left Hexagon
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (A.corner 2) {$v_{15}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (A.corner 3) {$v_{14}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (A.corner 4) {$v_{13}$};
\node[state, label=above:$1$] (12) at (A.corner 5) {$v_{12}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, except I need control over every node, because I need to label every node like in my example code given (I need to label them v_1 to v_15). Any idea how to adapt your code for that?

Comment: @Rhynden You have access to every node (A, B or C) and every corner (`A.corner 1`, ...). See updated answer where I've added point on every corner. Something similar can be used to add labels.

Comment: @Rhynden I've updated again with some labels on vertexes

Comment: Thanks! That's almost it! I pasted my newest code based on yours in my original question. I need to use a different node for the vertices and then the edges overlap. As a bonus, I would need to have the inner triangle also named.

Comment: I edited my original answer, since I got it working. I don't know if it's ideally coded, but it's looking perfect. Only thing I have is that if you draw the triangle, it isn't exactly the triangle that is created by A,B and C, therefore D isn't centered perfectly.
If you have a quick answer for that, I wouldn't mind. But else it is perfect as is. :)
Thanks!

Comment: @Rhynden I've update my answer with some changes over your code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

There are serious redudancies in your code and you can shrink it very easily by using `\foreach` and also insert your `label=above...` option into your tikzset.
Also, in order to simplify, you may replace your `triangle` tikzset by a simple barycentric definition of point D.
Your code worked really fine but I'd rather use a shorter one:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=6cm, outer sep=0pt},
state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2.5em, label=above:$1$}]
\node[hexagon] (A) {A};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 4] at (A.corner 1) (B){B};
\node[hexagon, anchor=corner 2] at (B.corner 5) (C){C};

\node at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {D};  % <---- Here

% Top Hexagon
\foreach \nodenum/\corner in {4/1,3/2,2/3,1/4,6/5,5/6}
    {
    \node[state] (\nodenum) at (B.corner \corner) {$v_{\nodenum}$};
    }

% Right Hexagon
\foreach \nodenum/\corner in {7/1,11/3,10/4,9/5,8/6}
    {
    \node[state] (\nodenum) at (C.corner \corner) {$v_{\nodenum}$};
    }
    

% Left Hexagon
\foreach \nodenum/\corner in {15/2,14/3,13/4,12/5}
    {
    \node[state] (\nodenum) at (A.corner \corner) {$v_{\nodenum}$};
    }

% Edges
\foreach \i in {1,...,14}{
    \path[-]
    (\i) edge node {} (\the\numexpr\i+1);
}
\path[-]
(1) edge node {} (6)
(6) edge node {} (11)
(11) edge node {} (1)
(15) edge node {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Same picture is produced so I didn't add any.